# how to config multiple vundle directories

Tags: vim, vundle

I'm new to vundle and I'm using exvim (exvim is a set of plugins and settings)

I have my own plugins to load and I want to put exvim and my own files separately, not modifying any setting of exvim's.

I create a **.vimrc** file to load **exivm's vimrc** and then **my own vimrc**

```
exec 'source ' . exvim_vimrc
exec 'source ' . my_vimrc
```

**exvim_vimrc** calls vundle first to load its plugins:

```
call vundle#rc(DIR_VUNDLE_EXVIM)   // DIR_VUNDLE_EXVIM contains all plugins that exvim uses
Plugin plugin_a   // load plugin a
Plugin plugin_b   // load plugin b
....
```

Let's say my plugins are in **d:/my_plugin**, how can I load them?

I tried add script below in my vimrc, but seems conflicting with exvim's plugin loading

```
call vundle#rc(my_plugin_path)
Plugin 'my_plugin_a'
Plugin 'my_plugin_b'
```

Thanks.

Comment: u only need to set `rtp += d:/my_plugin/` and just call `call vundle#rc()`. A remark ... u dont need `exec 'source ' . exvim_vimrc` but simply `source /path/to/rcfiles/exvim_vimrc`

Comment: not working, if I call *call vundle#rc()* or *call vundle#rc(my_plugin_path)*, then the plugins of exvims' won't be loaded. If I don't call *call vundle#rc()*, then my plugins are not loading

Answer (score 0):

The new version of exVim already used Vundle for plugins installation.

Check it here: http://exvim.github.io

Comment: I want to put my plugin outside exvim to make exvim clean, so if next time I use git to update exvim, it won't conflict. and I don't want to use the *~/* folder, because I'm the only user on my machine, and the *~/* folder would be gone when system reinstalled(I'm using Windows).

How can I load *d:/my_plugin* without modifying any setting of exvims'?

Comment: This can be done by calling vundle#rc() manually. However, in exVim you need to call it in the right place. If you check exvim/main/.vimrc.plugin you will see that at the first several line exVim specific the path to install plugins. You can follow the script but write it in the a new file named ".vimrc.plugin.local". exVim will parse this file after .vimrc.plugin been parsed.